# WooCommerce single product page quantity description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to add a description to single product page, just after the `- +` block, better placing the add-to-cart button below.

Something like this:

[image: result example]

Might you help me?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

JD

Answer (score 0):

You may use this hook **"woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button"** for edit the single product page

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','your_function');

function your_function($product){
//your own html
}
```

Comment: `$product` is not passed to this hook